# How do wildcards in BusterJS test paths get interpreted?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, buster.js

At the command line, what are the rules for using wildcards to specify the path to tests that BusterJS should run?  How do such paths get interpreted by BusterJS? That is, the value provided for the option `-t` as in the following:

`$ buster-test -t <some path that contains wildcards>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option "-t" ends up splitting the path on comma and matching the paths using the minimach library.

https://github.com/busterjs/buster-cli/blob/806e3b4c8201a25a4028c4f15b1333bb4e1fd3bd/lib/buster-cli/config.js#L70

It is documented here: https://npmjs.org/package/minimatch